# Get Tweets from EpiTwitterJson

Tags: php, json, twitter

I've been banging my head against the wall for a few days now trying to do something that should be so simple. I am trying to use Jaison Mathai's EpiTwitter library to retrieve tweets from my account. Here is my code to get my tweets:

```
<?php $twitterObj = new EpiTwitter($__TWITTER['ConsumerKey'], $__TWITTER['ConsumerSecret'],$__TWITTER['MyAccessToken'],$__TWITTER['MyAccessTokenSecret']);
$twitterInfo= $twitterObj->get_accountVerify_credentials();
$twitterInfo->response;
// ^ This part works fine, I can get my user info and profile pic and whatnot
$username = $twitterInfo->screen_name;
$tjson = $twitterObj->get('statuses/user_timeline.json', array("screen_name"=>$username));
```

As far as I can tell, ^ this also works as it should. If I var_dump($tjson), I can see the tweets that I want to access, among a HUGE mess of other data.

My question boils down to this: from this point, how can i simply print out each tweet returned? Here's what I've tried so far:

```
foreach($tjson as $tweet) print($tweet)
//^ Throws IllegalArgumentException, "Not an array or object"
foreach($tjson->responseText as $tweet) print($tweet)
//^ Warning: illegal argument. Doesn't print anything

print_r($tjson->response) //Prints NULL
```

I thought $tjson->response would be what I want, because in the __get method in EpiTwitterJson, there is a line: 
`$this->response = json_decode($this->responseText, 1);`. Right after this line if I `var_dump($this->response)`, I get my tweets along with a little less data than var_dump($tjson) before. If on that same line I `print($this->response['status']['text'])`, I get a nice string of my tweet, which is exactly what I want.

What I don't quite understand is why $this->response is set inside of the EpiTwitterJson class, but $tjson->response is NULL in my code. I've looked and looked and looked but I can't seem to find any code snippets to get tweets with this library specifically. I think it's just one of those things that must be so obvious and simple that my brain refuses to accept it.
Obviously I could just crawl through $tjson->responseText, but I thought the whole point of the EpiTwitterJson class was so I would not have to do that? The **ideal** answer to my question will be code to boil down my $tjson object so i can say

```
foreach(something as $tweet) //do stuff with the tweet
```

Second best answer would be code to do this with another library. I only chose the EpiTwitter lib because it 'supports async' which sounds kinda cool if I ever decide to use it, and because it seemed like the simplest (ie least lines of code on my part). Quite frankly I really care more about making this work than understanding it; I can figure out what it all means later on.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($tjson->response as $post){
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($post);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

this works for me.

for eg. u can get id of post like that $post['id'], or user name $post['user']['name']